# ServiceStack Auth API from PHP website

Tags: web-services, rest, authentication, servicestack

I have a ServiceStack API set up which uses the auth plugin to allow users to register through the api.

The front end UI is a PHP site. So when the user clicks 'log in via twitter' they are redirected to the ServiceStack API and then onto twitter, back to the ServiceStack APIv and then back to the PHP site.

My question is - how can I manage the auth between the PHP site and the ServiceStack API? Would giving the PHP site the auth token be the way forward? I'd want there to be some per request authentication - would I pass on some cookie info from the browser with each request?

[UPDATE]

So - the website is hosted at http://somedomain.com
and the api is hosted at api.subdomain.com

so they can share cookies

from that cookie the website can retrieve the ss-id, ss-pid and the X-UAId

I can see that the [Authenticate] attribute tries to get these values from the request

So... if we provide these values in the request the API should be able to authenticate based on that.

Except it can't

What else do I need to provide to allow this to work? Is this even possible?

Comment: I can see there is a X-UAId cookie set with the users id, should the PHP site just be sending that? Surely that leaves it wide open? Should I also be setting the oauth_token and passing that along to the API?

Comment: What will the ServiceStack API return to the PHP site? An auth token? If they share the same DB, then you can persist the token to the Database and then just let the PHP site read the token from there.

Comment: The api does all the backend stuff for the PHP site.

Comment: OK, well persist the token to the Database and whenever you need the token, ask the API to give you the token for the current user. In case there is no token, redirect the user to the to the ServiceStack's endpoint to login with Twitter.

Comment: but all the user needs to do to pretend to be someone else is to change the X-UAId in the cookie? We only want to allow twitter / fb login then use that to access our secure API - I'm just confused as to how I'm meant to secure my ServiceStack API and allow access to the PHP site

Comment: Since I need some more info, if you want me to help you, please join this room to chat:
http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35751/helping-iwayneo-with-a-problem